# a function to extract all subexpressions from an expression

Tags: expression-construction, traversal

Can somebody help me with a function `f` such that it extract all sub expressions (i.e. looking down the expression tree) from any expression given to it and also a list of heads it encounters as it moves down the expression tree.

For example, `f@(Sin[Log[Cos[a], Tan[Log[a, b]]]] // Inactivate)` gives `{
{
Inactive[Sin][Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]]],
Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]],
Inactive[Cos][a],
Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]],
a,
Inactive[Log][a,b],
a,
b
},
{
Inactive[Sin],
Inactive[Log],
Inactive[Cos],
Inactive[Tan],
Inactive[Log]
}
}`

Note: order of occurrence and duplicacy must be maintained

Explanation of Order of sub expressions (also the order in which heads are removed to move to the next sub expression)

first the full expression

[image]

next the expression starting from the second level (Head `Inactive[Sin]` is removed)

[image]

next the two expressions at level 3 (Head `Inactive[Log]` is removed)

[image]

[image]

next the two expression at level 4 from left to right (next the Head `Inactive[Cos]` and then `Inactive[Tan]` is removed moving from left to right)

[image]

[image]

finally the two expressions at the last level from left to right (lastly the Head `Inactive[Log]` is removed to arrive at the last level)

[image]

[image]

This is the general order i want to have for sub expressions and the also the order of removal of Heads.

Comment: I want inactive to be bound to the head it is making inactive, so in the example the output must be same except instead of `Sin`,`Log`,`Cos`,`Tan` there would be `Inactive[Sin]`,`Inactive[Log]`,`Inactive[Cos]`,`Inactive[Tan]`

Comment: I have attached the picture of the expression tree. Start from the full expression and then start cutting the heads from the top leaving the expressions below. For example first subexpression is the input expression itself. Next is the expression without the outer `Inactive[Sin]`. Next the expression in the two branches below and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
head[h_[___]] := h;
head[atom_] := Nothing;

deconstruct[expr_] := With[
  {temp = Flatten[Level[expr, {#}]& /@ Range[0, Depth[expr]], 1]},
  {temp, head /@ temp}
];
```

**Usage**

```
deconstruct[Sin[Log[Cos[a], Tan[Log[a, b]]]] // Inactivate]

(*
  {
   {Inactive[Sin][Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]]], 
    Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]],
    Inactive[Cos][a], 
    Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]], 
    a, 
    Inactive[Log][a, b], 
    a, 
    b
   }, 
   {Inactive[Sin], 
    Inactive[Log], 
    Inactive[Cos], 
    Inactive[Tan], 
    Inactive[Log]}
   }

*)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 3):

### Second answer

The OP's desired order:

```
oporder = {
 {Inactive[Sin][Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]]], 
    Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]], Inactive[Cos][a], 
    Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]], a, Inactive[Log][a, b], a, b},
 {Inactive[Sin], Inactive[Log], Inactive[Cos], Inactive[Tan], 
    Inactive[Log]}};

SetAttributes[ff, HoldFirst];
ff[expr_] := Reap[
   Do[
    (Sow[#, "expr"]; Sow[Head[#], "head"] & /@ #) &@Level[expr, {k}],
    {k, 0, Depth[expr] - 1}],
   {"expr", "head"},
   Sequence @@ If[# === "head", Replace[#2, _?AtomQ -> Nothing, 1], Flatten@#2] &] // Last
```

This is similar to the first approach except that it goes down the expression level by level, so that no reversing is needed.  One can remove the `Flatten` if if having the expressions collected by level happens to be desired.

```
ff[Sin[Log[Cos[a], Tan[Log[a, b]]]] // Inactivate]
(*
  {{Inactive[Sin][Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]]], 
    Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]],
     Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]], a, Inactive[Log][a, b], a, b},
   {Inactive[Sin], Inactive[Log], Inactive[Cos], Inactive[Tan], Inactive[Log]}}
*)

% === oporder
(*  True  *)
```

### First answer

How's this? [Update remark: `Reverse` reverses not only the depths of the levels but the order at each level]

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[expr_] := Reap[
   Scan[
    (Sow[#, "expr"]; Sow[Head[#], "head"]) &,
    expr,
    Infinity],
   {"expr", "head"},
   Sequence @@ 
     If[# === "head", #2 /. {Symbol -> Nothing}, Reverse@#2] &
   ] // Last

f[Sin[Log[Cos[a], Tan[Log[a, b]]]] // Inactivate]
(*
  {{
   Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a],
   Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]],
   Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]],
   Inactive[Log][a, b],
   b,
   a, 
   Inactive[Cos][a],
   a},
   {
    Inactive[Cos],
    Inactive[Log],
    Inactive[Tan], 
    Inactive[Log]
    }
   }
*)
```

(I wasn't really sure whether the `Inactivate` was suppose to be part of `f` or of the expression.  I was also unsure about the order and whether `Reverse` does what you want.)

Comment: Hi Michael your code is almost what i want but can you please make the output order exactly what i have written. Also please make it output the full expression as well. I can't do this myself since i have no understanding of how `Reap`, `Sow` and `Scan` works. Thank you

Comment: @user13892 How to **define** the order?  "`Scan` traverses the parts of `expr` in a depth-first order, with leaves visited before roots," according to the docs.  What order do you want in general (not just the specific example)?

Comment: see my updated question with pictures describing the general methodology to move to the next subexpression and also collect the heads in the order they are removed.

Comment: replacing a,b by actual numbers like 2, 2.0 results in Integer, Real appearing in the list of Heads removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the head `Inactive[]` complicates this a bit, but generally, you'll want to do this:

```
DeleteCases[DeleteCases[Reap[Scan[
 Sow[#] &, (Sin[Log[Cos[a], Tan[Log[a, b]]]] // Inactivate), {0, 
  Infinity}, Heads -> True]][[2, 1]], Inactive[x_]], Inactive]
```

> {Sin, Log, Cos, a, Inactive[Cos][a], Tan, Log, a, b, 
>    Inactive[Log][a, b], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]], 
>    Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]], 
>    Inactive[Sin][
>     Inactive[Log][Inactive[Cos][a], 
>      Inactive[Tan][Inactive[Log][a, b]]]]}

Comment: This is treating `Inactive` as a separate head. I want it to be bound to the head it is making inactive

Comment: @user13892 How about this then?